# Can't get header files to work

Tags: c++, class, header

I'm learning about header files and classes right now, and I can't seem to get them to work. I don't see what I'm doing wrong. I've included the errors as comments where the compiler said there were errors. How do I fix this?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Header.h" //Error: In file included from C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\
                             C++ Practice\Header Practice\Main.cpp 

int main()
{
    Header Test;
    Test.Header(); Error: invalid use of `class Header' 

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Header.h

```
#ifndef Header_H_
 #define Header_H_

 class Header
{
 public:
        void Header(); //Error: return type specification for constructor invalid 
};

#endif // Header_H_
```

and Header.cpp.

```
#include "Header.h"

Header::Header()
{
 std::cout << "Everything is working./n" << std::flush;
};
```

Comment: Constructors do not have a type specifier. Remove the `void` from `void Header();` in Header.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `void` from `void Header();` in `Header.h`

in `Header.cpp`, remove the semicolon:

```
#include "Header.h"

Header::Header()
{
 std::cout << "Everything is working./n" << std::flush;
}; <------ REMOVE SEMICOLON
```

in `main.cpp` - you're calling the constructor wrong by doing this `Test.Header()`.

you should be doing either `Header Test;` or `Header *Test = new Header()`

Comment: I did everything you said, but I'm getting a linker error. It says "  [Linker error] undefined reference to `Header::Header()'." How do I fix this? It was caused after I deleted Test.Header().

Comment: @BrandonHoutzer. How are you compiling it. It sounds like you are just compiling main. `g++ main.cpp Header.cpp` should work.

Comment: @BrandonHoutzer did you do what Loki said? what platform are you on (Linux, Mac, Windows)?

Comment: @Loki Astari: I'm using Dev C++. I've compiled each of them. I'm still getting a linker error when I compile main.

Comment: @BrandonHoutzer DevC++ is not very good. i just tested your code with the corrections above and it compiles fine.

Comment: @BrandonHoutzer: I assume you mean Dev Studio the MS integrated development environment? In which case all the source should be in a project and you compile the project. The environment knows to link all the source files together.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `void` from `void Header();` line. Constructors are declared without return type.